# Portland group FORTRAN pgf90 program fails when compiled with -fast, succeeds with -fast -Mnounroll

Tags: optimization, crash, fortran, pgi

This code hummed along merrily for a long time, until we recently discovered an edge case where it fails silently-- no errors returned.
The fail is apprently pretty subtle. We can get the code to run uneventfully in the edge case by:

1) compiling with any set of options that includes `-traceback` or debug (`-g` or `-gopt`);

2) compiling with `-fast -Mnounroll`;

3) compiling with optimization <2;

4) adding WRITE statements into the code to determine the location of the fail;

In other words, most of the tools useful for debugging the failure-- actually result in the failure disappearing.

I am probing for any information on failures related to loop unrolling or other optimization, and their resolution.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pgf (heck, it's been 10 years since I used any fortran), but here are some general suggestions for tracking down (potential) compiler bugs:

1. Simplify a reproducible case. I.e. try to reproduce the problem with a similar looking piece of code that has all the superfluous details removed. This is helpful because a) you'll be less hesitant to release the code publicly, and b) if someone attempts to diagnose the problem, it will be easier for them with less surrounding material.
2. Talk to the experts: If you have a support contract for pgf, use it! There's a [support request form](https://www.pgroup.com/support/support_request.php) on their site. If not, there's a User Forums section where you might be able to post your information - someone else may have better workaround, or an employee there may be able to log your problem.
3. Double-check your code. Is it possible that you're relying on some sort of [unspecified behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior)? This is the sort of thing that would cause your program to switch behavior when changing optimization levels. I'm not saying compiler bugs are impossible, but it could be a hack in your code too.

Hope that's helpful.